# laravel 5.2 Auth::loginUsingId() not working when i redirect to another page

Tags: facebook, laravel-5

I am Implementing Facebook Login in my Laravel Project. for this I have used Facebook JS code. Its working fine I receiving data also. Now i want to save data in my database and login with this inserted id.
For this I have created a function called "checkloginByFacebook_API" in a controller and put below code also

```
$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['checkloginByFacebook_API']]);
```

now I am using below method

```
$auth_data = Auth::loginUsingId(1);</code>
```

Here it print `$auth _data` array but if I change page it don't show its value means Auth session not worked.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: are you sure that the new user has `id = 1`?

Comment: yes, I have passed id dynamic as well static 1
And its working just after login means if I print <code>$auth _data</code> it print array but when i redirect to another page it lost its value means session not persisting

Comment: Have you solved it?